# What is the best practice for organizing a piece of reusable code?

Tags: python, oop, code-organization

I am building a text-based encryption and decryption game.  There are different levels, and each level uses a different cipher for encrypting a text.  I am trying to figure out the best practice for the series of questions and prompts (the narrative) I give the user to determine if he wants to practice, do the test, encrypt, or decrypt.  90% of the narrative is the same for each level, so I don't want to repeat myself with identical code.  What is the best way to do this?

My first thought was to define a function that contained the general script, and to call the specific functions as parameters.  (This is what I have attempted to do below).  But I seem to run into a scope problem.  When I call the `caesar()` function as one of the arguments in the `script()` function, I need to enter the text to be encrypted, but this text isn't provided by the user until the `script()` function has already started running.

Should I be using a `class` to define the narrative portion of the program, and then inherit to more specific types?

Or should I just repeat the narrative code at the different levels?

Here is the narrative `script()`:

```
def script(encrypt, decrypt):
    """Asks user if they want to practice (encode or decode) or take the
    test, and calls the corresponding function."""
encrypt = encrypt
decrypt = decrypt

    while True:
        print('Type Q to quit.  Type M to return to the main menu.')
        prac_test = input('would you like to practice or take the test? P/T')
        if prac_test.lower() == 'p':
            choice = input('Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? E/D ')
            if choice.lower() == 'e':
                text = input('Enter the text you would like to encode: ')
                encrypt
            elif choice.lower() == 'd':
                text = input('Enter the text you would like to decode: ')
                key = int(input('Enter the key: '))
                decrypt
            else:
                print('You must enter either "E" or "D" to encode or decode a
                  text. ')
        elif prac_test.lower() == 't':
            text = random.choice(text_list)
            encrypted_text = encrypt
            print(encrypted_text[0])
            answer = input('s/nCan you decode this string? ')
            if answer.lower() == ran_str.lower():
                print('Congrats! You solved level 1!\n')
                pass
            elif answer != ran_str:
                print("Sorry, that's not correct.  Why don't you practice some
                   more?\n")
                script(encrypt, decrypt)
        elif prac_test.lower() == 'q':
            exit()
        elif prac_test.lower() == 'm':
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid choice.')
```

Here is one of the levels using a caesar cipher:

```
def caesar(mode, text, key=None):
    """
...
The dictionaries that convert between letters and numbers are stored in the .helper file, imported above.
    """
    mode = mode
    if mode == 'encrypt':
        key = random.randint(1, 25)
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
        key = key
    str_key = str(key)
    text = text.lower()
    # converts each letter of the text to a number
    num_list = [alph_to_num[s] if s in alph else s for s in text]
    if mode == 'encrypt':
        # adds key-value to each number
        new_list = [num_to_alph[(n + key) % 26] if n in num else n for n in
                    num_list]
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
        # subtracts key-value from each number
        new_list = [num_to_alph[(n - key) % 26] if n in num else n for n in
                    num_list]
    new_str = ''
    for i in new_list:
        new_str += i
    return new_str, str_key
```

And here is who I would try to use them together:

```
script(caesar('encrypt' text), caesar('decrypt', text, key))
```

Please instruct me on the best way to organize this reusable narrative code.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: I just fixed the indentation.

Comment: `def script(encrypt, decrypt):` still has wonky indentation. The `while` loop is presumably part of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use multiple functions:

- One, that we will call `main()`, to display the menu and interact with the user
- A class `Caesar`, that expose two functions: `encrypt(text, key)` and `decrypt(text, key)`

A simple program could then look like

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the game")
    action = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a text [e/d]">).lower()
    text = input("What is the text you want to test on ? >")
    key = input("What's your key")
    # optionnaly, ask for what kind of cipher they want to use, then use a dict to chose the right class
    cipher = Caesar()
    if action == "e":
         output = cipher.encrypt(text, key=key)
    else:
         output = cipher.decrypt(text, key=key)

    print(output)
    print("Thanks for playing!")
```